# Nginx - Wordpress, Mediawiki etc

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I am thinking to get to know nginx better, I have a home box which I can install Fedora, Ubuntu or any flavor linux.

Goal : To have a wordpress (blog), mediawiki (wiki), forum script in subdirectories under the www root.

so for e.g. www.mydyndnsdomain.com/blog, /wiki/, /forum and so on.

I setup a fedora13 VM, installed nginx on it, edited the nginx.conf to specify web root /usr/share/nginx/html/ - I can see the index.html (default nginx page) but when i put wordpress into a subdirectory called blog it won't get displayed or allow me to start the install process of wp.

Any step by step would be really helpful
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a reasonable write-up on using PHP with nginx. As @Ron said, you need to start up the PHP FCGI processes, and then tell nginx to use them.

http://tomasz.sterna.tv/2009/04/php-fastcgi-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-12
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-12-p2
I used the above how-tos to get it installed on fedora13. It seems that it now has the ability to handle php fast cgi process (not sure though - as this is the first time with nginx or even nix based webservers).

I did a phpinfo.php on the root of the webserver and it displays php info page so it is handling php fine.
Can you please guide me on how to get the wordpress, mwiki etc working from under one web root folder-Thanks

Comment: I recommend you read the installation instructions for each piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

If you now have PHP executing, what are the errors you are getting trying to install these applications?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this guide](http://elasticdog.com/2008/02/howto-install-wordpress-on-nginx/). Here author uses lighttpd for spawning fcgi processes. I think this will help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's great to hear that you're interested in getting to know Nginx better and setting up a WordPress blog, MediaWiki, and forum script on your home box. To achieve your goal of having these applications in subdirectories under the www root, you've already made progress by setting up a Fedora13 VM, installing Nginx, and editing the nginx.conf file to specify the web root as /usr/share/nginx/html/.

Regarding the specific issue you're facing with WordPress not being displayed or allowing you to start the installation process when placed in a subdirectory called "blog," it could be due to configuration settings or permissions. A step-by-step guide would indeed be helpful to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

In the meantime, here are a few suggestions to consider:

Double-check the file and folder permissions within the "blog" subdirectory to ensure they are properly set for the [web server](https://www.laptopicker.com/04-best-laptops-with-ethernet-port/) to access and serve the WordPress files.
Review the Nginx configuration file to ensure that the server block for the "blog" subdirectory is correctly defined and includes the necessary directives to handle PHP files.
Confirm that the necessary PHP modules and dependencies are installed and configured correctly on your Fedora13 VM.
For more detailed guidance, I recommend checking online resources, such as Nginx's official documentation or community forums, where you can find step-by-step tutorials and troubleshooting guides specific to your setup. Good luck with your Nginx exploration and setting up your desired web applications!

Answer (score -1):

Last time I looked at nginx, it does not have the ability to directly manage its own FastCGI processes.  You would need to write your own script to start up the PHP FastCGI processes, then configure Nginx to pass requests to the FastCGI sockets before any PHP applications will work.

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-12
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-12-p2

with reference to the above how-to, do you think nginx can handle the php fast cgi process ? I think it can - not sure - your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nginx will not spawn the processes for you no. Either use spawn-fcgi and use supervisord, monit etc to monitor them or be awesome and go with PHP 5.3.3 compiled with --enable-fpm

Comment: Martin F, Thanks for your input :
can you plz explain a bit more on this ? As i mentioned I am new to the nix world of web servers etc.
1) Do I just download 5.3.3
2) Install Nginx (according to the how-to I followed)

Kind Regards